# Generar BigInteger aleatorio de tamaño exactamente K

Tags: java, random, bigdecimal

Buenas, no sabría como generar `n` BigInteger de longitud `K` constante.
Encontré este algoritmo aquí:

```
BigInteger r;  
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());  

do {  
    r = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rnd);  
} while (r.compareTo(n) >= 0);
```

Este satisfactoriamente genera números aleatorios en un rango, pero no es lo que busco, lo que busco es por ejemplo:

```
Input   
n = 3  
k = 5  

Output  
12345  
54321  
67854
```

Comment: si genera en un rango.... usa el rango desde 10.000 hasta 99.999, o no?

Comment: podrias especificar mas tu preguntas por favor, de ser posible añade el codigo el cual utilizaste y explica por que no es de tu ayuda

Comment: Buena observación, intentaré algo teniéndolo en cuenta.

Comment: que es rdn? y rango?, puedes agregar eso, que tipos son y que tienen?

Comment: Listo, agregue los tipos de las variables.

Comment: me complica lo de bitLength. Ya que es potencia de 2, con 2^17 son aleatorios entre 0 y 131.072 :( lo unico que se me ocurre es hacer una proporción, una especie de interpolación entre 0/10000 a 99999/131.072 para no alterar la distribucion de los aleatorios. Ya que cualquier tipo de truncamiento en teoría deberia alterar

Comment: Olvide corregir algo: rango vendría siendo n, el limite superior, es exclusivo.

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random)) el numero BigInteger que se genera es entre 0 y 2^numBits. rnd solo es el objeto semilla desde donde se sacan los bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supongo que lo de "longitud K constante" en realidad se refiere a que, escrito el número en base decimal, la cantidad de digitos es K.

(Nunca confundas un número -un ente matemático- con su representación; por ejemplo: `251` `0xFB` `2.51E2` `CCLI` son distintas representaciones -en notación decimal, hexadecimal, científica y romana- pero el número es uno y el mismo en los cuatro casos; no son cuatro números, es uno solo escrito de maneras diferentes)

En tal caso, si por ejemplo K=5 tienes que generar en el rango 10000 a 99999, es decir, entre 10^(K-1) y 10^K-1

La manera más eficiente de generar BigInteger aleatorios es generando [directamente los bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054262/get-random-biginteger-in-range-x-y), pero eso no se adapta directamente a un rango decimal. (aunque puede hacerse, generando valores unformes en el rango 0 - 2^j-1 para cierto j tal que 2^j >= 10^(k+1) y verificando si cae dentro de nuestro rango, si no es así reintentamos)

Otra opción sencilla es generar directamente el numero como string y luego convertirlo a BigInteger

```
public static BigInteger randBi(int digitosDecimales) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i = 0; i < digitosDecimales; i++ ) {
        int ir = i == 0 ? rand.nextInt(9) + 1 : rand.nextInt(10);
        s.append((char) ('0' + ir));
    }
    return new BigInteger(s.toString());
}
```

O, algo más elegante (no sé si más eficiente) usando aritmética con BigInteger:

```
public static BigInteger randBi2(int digitosDecimales) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    BigInteger bi=BigInteger.ZERO;
    for( int i = 0; i < digitosDecimales; i++ ) {
        int ir = i == 0 ? rand.nextInt(9) + 1 : rand.nextInt(10);
        bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(BigInteger.valueOf(ir));
    }
    return bi;
}
```

Ambas pueden optimizarse un poco, si las vas a usar repetidamente: el objeto Random debería instanciarse una sola vez, por ejemplo. Y en la segunda implentación, podríamos prearmar los diez BigInteger 0-9 en un array.

Comment: Excelente como abordaste el problema. Generas los dígitos en string vez de cuadrarlo matemáticamente :P +1 (como no se me ocurrió antes jajaja)

Comment: Excelente, me queda un largo camino por recorrer. Gracias.

Comment: Con una simple prueba de crear 100.000 códigos de longitud 500, con el System.currentTimeMillis() el primer algoritmo es aproximadamente 61% más rápido que el segundo.

Comment: @VictorPaternina Si, yo tengo mas o menos el mismo resultado (tambien despues de optimizar) y la diferencia parece aumentar cuando usamos BigIntegers realmente "Big"....

Answer (score 1):

Puedes construir una representación de cadena de los valores aleatorios usar el constructor `BigInteger(String val)' :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class BigInt {

    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=4;
        int k=80;
        BigInt bi = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(bi.random(k));
        }
    }

    public BigInteger random(int k){
        byte[] ba = new byte[k];
        ba[0] = (byte) (sr.nextInt(9)+49);
        for (int d = 1;d<k;d++){
            ba[d] = (byte) (sr.nextInt(10)+48); 
        }
        return new BigInteger(new String(ba));
    }
}
```